# iterate over async function result in svelte

Tags: svelte

I am trying to iterate over some value returned by some async function.

```
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

let navigation;

onMount(async function(){
    navigation = FETCHER.data.navigation;
    console.log(navigation);
});
```

then in html

```
{#await navigation}
    {#each navigation.main as menuItem}
        foobar
    {/each}
{/await}
```

however "foobar" never comes to light.

Inside navigation I find this datastructure:

```
main: (3) […]
0: Object { ID: 16, url: "http://127.0.0.1/", title: "Welcome", … }
1: Object { ID: 15, url: "http://127.0.0.1/", title: "Home", … }
2: Object { ID: 176, url: "http://127.0.0.1/test/", title: "test", … }
length: 3
```

I am really curious why anything inside the await block isn't rendered at all. Am I doing something wrong with the promise?

One thing on a sidenote which may be important: the FETCHER.data.navigation variable is passed through from WordPress using wp_localize_script, hence no fetch call whatsoever going out.

Thanks for any input in advance.

Best,
Sebo

Comment: what is `FETCHER.data.navigation`? A promise?

Comment: it's an object injected from WordPress via wp_localize_script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax for `await` needs a [then block](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks):

```
{#await navigation}
    <p>awaiting...</p>
{:then navigation}
    {#each navigation.main as menuItem}
        foobar
    {/each}
{:catch error}
    <p>error</p>
{/await}
```

That, however, depends on the fact that the promise resolves correctly, and in the case of an async function, needs a **return value**. In the code here, nothing is returned from the async function, which will not resolve correctly.

So correcting the await block syntax and returning a value from the promise, the following should work:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let promise;
    async function fetchStuff() {
        return FETCHER.data.navigation;
    }
    onMount(() => {
        promise = fetchStuff();
    });
</script>

{#await promise}
<p>
    awaiting...
</p>
{:then navigation}
<p>
    here access navigation
</p>
{:catch error}
<p>
    oh noes.
</p>
{/await}
```